# Find Document in MongoDB by array name with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

Trying to figure out how to use MongoDB in python and have come up against a roadblock. Any help is much appreciated. Please note that I have read the MongoDB Python Tutorial and the W3 site to no avail.

The data in my DB is stored as such:
[image: MongoDB Data Structure]

I would like to be able to find a document by the Array Name (highlighted in orange). If this is not possible then is it possible to set the `_id` field to a string in python that I can get documents by?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection_name.find_one({array_name: {"$exists": true}})
```